# Where is the correct location to put log4j.jar in my java directory?

Tags: cmd, compiler-errors, log4j, javac

I'm trying to compile some .java files in command prompt using "javac *.java -Xlint" and I must include log4j.jar somewhere in my java-jdk directory obviously, because I'm getting "package org.apache.log4j does not exist" error.

Where should I put the log4j.jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually projects are built using some build tool like maven or ant.

But if you want to build it using `javac` I would suggest you to create the next project structure:

```
YourCoolProject
  ├ src
  | └ com
  |   └ companyname
  |     └ Main.java
  ├ lib
  | └ log4j.jar
  └ build
```

(you paccage will look like this `com.companyname`).

Then you can compile your code using next command (you have to run console in `YourCoolProject` folder):

```
javac -d ./build -classpath "lib/*" -sourcepath src src/com/companyname/Main.java
```

In this case everything you add into `/lib` folder will be automatically included to classpath. Using this command your code will be compiled into `/build` folder.